# JavaCC - How can I remove all choice-conflicts in this statement without lookahead?

Tags: java, javacc, regex-lookarounds, ambiguity

I'm currently developing a parser to my grammar. My objective is to make it without lookaheads, and this is the one that I am really struggling with.

Here is a minified example that I believe is enough to demonstrate the problem i'm having.

```java
void main() : {}
{
    (A())* (B())*
}

void A() : {}
{
    C() <ID>
}

void B() : {}
{
    <ID> Z()
}

void C() : {}
{
    <bah>
    | <bha>
    | <ID>
}
```

This is the output warning (I want to remove it)

```
Warning: Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 200, column 23.
         Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
         have common prefixes, one of which is: <ID>
         Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExcange.  What is Z?

Answer (score 1):

Really we need to know more about `Z`.  I'll assume that L(`Z`) (i.e. the language generated by `Z`) does not contain the empty sequence and contains no sequences that start with an `ID`, `bha`, or `bah`.  I'll also assume that the first token after `main` can't be `ID`, `bha`, or `bah`.

In this situation, I'd almost certainly use lookahead

```
void main() : {}
{
    AsBs()
}

void AsBs() : {}
{ 
  LOOKAHEAD( A() )
  A() AsBs() ;
|
  (B()*)
|
  {/*nothing*/}
}
```

with `A`, `B`, and `C` as in the original post.

---

However, the poster wants a solution without using lookahead.  Here is one. I made the same assumptions as above.

```
void main() : {}
{
    AsBs()
}

void AsBs() : {}
{
    C1() <ID> AsBs()
|
    <ID>  // This ID might be the start of either A or B
    ( <ID> AsBs()  // That ID started an A
    | Z() (B())* ) // That ID started a B.
|
    {/*nothing*/}
}

void B() : {}
{
    <ID> Z()
}

void C1() : {}
{
    <bah>
    | <bha>
}
```

There is no need for `A` or `C` here.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough! All the assumptions made are correct. And thank you for this solution